# Add a space between results in ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I use the following ng-repeat:

```
<b>Mots clés :</b><span ng-repeat="resulKeywords in resultats.tra_keywords"><span ng-bind-html="resulKeywords | highlight:rechercheKeywords"></span></span>
```

It works and display all my resulKeywords.
Sample display:

```
 result1result2result3result4
```

How can i add a space between my result ?

```
 result1 result2 result3 result4
```

All my test fail because i encaspuled the results in a ng-bind-html.

Comment: can you post a plunkr/jsfiddle of your problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to add

`<span ng-bind-html="resulKeywords | highlight:rechercheKeywords"></span> &nbsp;`

Comment: cool , if you dont have any other question you can mark it as an answered :)